# WMI : Setting IP (with SQL Server database)

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, networking

How to setting up my IP address getting the value in the database?

This is my `SqlCommand`:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();

    var query = "SELECT TOP 1 ip_address, subnet, gateway FROM computer_info WHERE pc_name = HOST_NAME() ORDER BY id DESC";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        // column ip
        string ip_address = dr["ip_address"].ToString();
        string sub_net = dr["subnet"].ToString();
        string gateway = dr["gateway"].ToString();

        label1.Text = ip_address;
        label2.Text = sub_net;
        label3.Text = gateway;
    }

    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{   
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

This is my code for changing my ip address and subnet:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                    ManagementBaseObject newIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                    string x = label1.Text;
                    string z = label2.Text;
                    newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { x };
                    newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { z };

                    setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I press the button, there is no changes happening.

Question 1: why if I not use my database value my code is working. I don't know why it happens. This is the sample code that my codes is work fine:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                ManagementBaseObject newIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                string x = "192.168.1.15";
                string z = "255.255.255.0"

                newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { x };
                newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { z };

                setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be trying to modify your IP address in code.  Windows doesn't allow it so hackers can't spoof your PC.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean ?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the IP address.   Does not work.  You should be modifying the connection string to connect to the SQL Server.  Is the SQL on same PC or different PC?  The connection string contains the SQL Server Name (IP).  No need to modify your PC IP address in the Network adapter.

Comment: i want to change other computer  ip address but updating in admin form. then in user form automatically the user will update new ip address

Comment: You want to connect to a SQL database in the 2nd PC.  So change the connection string, not the PC IP address.

Comment: This is the scenario. The admin can update the user computer ip address by pressing the button update.

Comment: how to chat you @jdweng

Comment: i already connected to the admin database. string connection = "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=xxxx;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxxx;"; i just want to select the data from the database then update automatically my ip address. by selecting

Comment: @jdweng to understand well. i want to select the ip address,subnet what admin put to the database...